# How does incredimail import email accounts automatically?

Tags: security, email, outlook

I installed incredimail yesterday to experiment with something. To my surprise I found out that it was able to pull email accounts from windows live mail including my ***username and password!!*** How is it possible for incredimail to do it?

More serious concern is what stops spyware/virus programs to do the same? Is this a big security concern?

I did some research and found that email accounts were stored in .IAF files till outlook 2002 and they are in proprietary format.

Links -
Incredimail help site -http://help.incredimail.com/incredimail/help_center/help_article.aspx?is=t&article_id=6
IAF file info - http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/iaf

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, Incredimail **IS** spyware.
And why not? It's a plugin, which means it has access to whatever your email client does...

Oh, and spamware too - I keep getting mails from them, just because my mom sent me an email with it a couple years ago... :@

Is it a security concern? Only if you (or anyone you know) installs it...

Answer (score 0):

Incredimail probably recognizes the username and password which are stored by Windows Live Mail in a format which can be decoded and extracted. Remember that it has full access to your system and it can browse to the locations where Windows Live Mail stores its settings and data. So it is not that Windows Live Mail stores your username and password in irreversible format because, remember, it still needs to send them to the server when authenticating and fetching your emails. So they need to be known to the program in plain-text format and this needs to be stored somewhere on the disk. It is not too hard to figure out where Windows Live Mail stores such data and extract it, given the fact that Incredimail had access to your system.

In fact, entire account settings can be exported from Windows Live Mail into an IAF file format which is capable of storing your whole account settings data such as username, password, server names and other settings required to connect.

IAF files are no longer used but for the purpose of decoding data from it you can use online decoder such as this one - http://www.oeclassic.com/iaf-decoder